# How to show product total price calculation in Magento cart

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, shopping-cart

I'm having problems trying to show the product full total price in Magento, and by product total price I mean full product price without the discount; the price has to be multiplied for each product quantity added to the cart, and custom options additional price should be added as well. Which files should I edit in Magento? is it possible to show the product discount inside the cart (amount that varies with the amount of ordered products)? 
Thanks

Edit:
[screenshot](http://oi62.tinypic.com/znv8rr.jpg)

In the blue rectangle it shows the regular price, which should be regular price X 2 (since product quantity is 2) with added 122€ as chosen in product special options. Instead now it shows regular price with discount applied and for only 1 product, without special option added.

Comment: What do you want to do actually? Need more information.

Comment: I added a screenshot and some more info

Comment: Use Template path hints to get to know more about which files you need to edit

Comment: we managed to display unit price and subtotal (not the way we wanted but at least now it is understandable for clients), but there is still a problem with the discount: is it possible to show the product discount inside the cart (amount that varies with the amount of ordered products)?